# openpyxl - get input from QLineEdit and save in excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to use openpyxl to get the user input from a QLineEdit and save it to an Excel file. The script below works well when no QLineEdit is envolved but is not working under openpyxl. The error message I get is: cannot convert QlineEdit to Excel.

```
self.le.setText(str(text))
text = self.le.text()
wb = load_workbook (source_file)
ws = wb.active
ws.append ([text])
wb.save (source_file)
```

What would be a way to this? C

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that with more code I could provide a more certain answer, but QT has several problems with typing in python. More specifically it returns 'Qtypes' for a lot of common python types that need to be manually converted before they can be serialized. Try this:

```
self.le.setText(str(text))
text = str(self.le.text())
wb = load_workbook (source_file)
ws = wb.active
ws.append ([text])
wb.save (source_file)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Robert, that solved the issue. Thanks for your time.